# JavaFX Timeline Include Minutes and Seconds

Tags: java, javafx

I have a Timer working with JavaFX but all it will count is seconds. How would I get it to do Minutes and Seconds.

```
timeline = new Timeline();
        timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.getKeyFrames().add(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1),
                        //new  {
                        new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                            // KeyFrame event handler
                            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                                remaining--;
                                // update timerLabel
                                timeStamp.setText(
                                        remaining.toString());
                                if (remaining <= 0) {
                                    timeline.stop();
                                }
                            }
                        }));
        timeline.playFromStart();
```

Comment: Not if what I am calculating is a Double. It will countdown everything before the decimal.

Answer (score 1):

```
Duration newValue=timeline.getCurrentTime();    
int hTime = (int) newValue.toHours();
int minTime = (int) newValue.toMinutes();
int secTime= (int) newValue.toSeconds();
    if(secTime/60>=1){ // this are to display later something like a clock 19:02:20
      secTime%=60; //if you want just the time in minutes use only the toMinutes() 
    }
    if(minTime/60>=1){
      minTime%=60;
    }
```

hTime = time in hours

minTime = time in minutes

secTime = time in seconds

usually the timeline works with millis so you have to be careful ;)

Answer (score 0):

You Use getTime Method

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/KeyFrame.html

I think this will help you .

Answer (score 0):

You may use `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit` class which provides nice conversion facilities

```
int min = 3;
int sec = 14;
double totalSec = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(min) + sec;
```